# converting integers to decimals in a string

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a string of mathematical function that looks like this:

```
add(multiply(1, 4461.2419), multiply(subtract(X1, 5), 475.5))
```

I would like to extract only the integers and convert them to decimals and then reappend them to the string. For example, I want the output to look like:

```
add(multiply(1.0, 4461.2419), multiply(subtract(X1, 5.0), 475.5))
```

How do I go about doing that? Also, please note that 'X1' is a variable name so I don't want the 1 in the variable name converted to float.

So far I have tried something like this to identify the integers:

```
s = "add(multiply(1, 4461.2419), multiply(subtract(X1, 5), 475.5))"
print(re.findall("[-+]?\d+", s))
```

But it gives this result:

```
['1', '4461', '2419', '1', '5', '475', '5']
```

and seems to split the decimals as well. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me what you have tried till now? Can you add a snippet of code and errors if any?

Comment: Try a regular expression.

Comment: See what I have so far. Appreciate you looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str1= 'add(multiply(1, 4461.2419), multiply(subtract(X1, 5), 475.5))'

def replf(matchobj):
     a= matchobj.group(0)
     float= re.findall('\d+',a)[0]+'.0'
     return re.sub('\d+', float,a)

print re.sub('[\(\,\s](\d+)[\)\,\s]' ,replf,str1)   #no decimals allowed
```

output:

```
add(multiply(1.0, 4461.2419), multiply(subtract(X1, 5.0), 475.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so pretty but I have put **regex** to the use. Probably there is a better answer

```
import re

fnStr = 'add(multiply(1, 4461.2419), multiply(subtract(X1, 5), 475.5))'

# initializing the string to store the final value
finalStr = ''

# looks like it is always going to be that integers will end up as parameters to function calls, so splitting them using commas and looping the parts over
for i in fnStr.split(', '):
    # following is for ignoring the floats and also the variables which are of form X1
    if '.' in i and not re.search('\w\d',i):
        finalStr += i+', '
    #This is where we detect the integer and convert in to float and replace the string
    else:
        finalStr += re.sub('\d',str(float(re.search('\d',i).group(0))), i) +', '

# finally stripping the last comma and space added as a sideeffect of the previous loop
print finalStr.rstrip(', ')
```

EDIT:  You might want to have the logic of detecting variables changed to `re.search('\w+\d+',i)` if you think variables can be of any name like `XX11`

Answer (score -1):

This regex, combined with the function you used above re.findall(), should give you all the numbers:

```
[^a-zA-Z_0-9.]([\d.]+)
```

it excludes numbers from variables names like:

```
aa123 
as_123 
AS123_
```

and all other similar combinations. Very strange variable names could cause some malfunction like:

```
as%1234
fds$121
asfas#231
```

If you are planing to use that special chars to name your variables, add them to the brackets. Once you get all the numbers, you should be able to transform them to float, and append them without much hassle.